# Open Layers + jquery

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I am doing my master thesis on Internet mapping. My task is to display research work at my department on webpage on top of Google Maps. So far I was successful in that, but my problem is that I am not able to find the way connect layers on the map to individual row on the table in the same page. i am trying to use jquery to some how link row in the table with layer on the map. can any body help me how to do that. 
you can see my work below:

```
[http://130.237.175.39/goran_1.html][1]
```

In my page i have created two div elements for map object and table. i am posting those two elements of the code here. if you want to see full code you can see it in page source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Land Uplift</title>
    <script src="http://193.10.6.144/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://130.237.186.211/geoserver/scalebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://130.237.186.211/geoserver/mousepos.css">
    </head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;text-align:center;">Land Uplift Project</h1></div>
<div id="table" style="height:100px;width:200px;margin-left:50px;">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Layer</th>
<th>Layer Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5000_fKr</td>
<td>4500_fKr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4000_fKr</td>
<td>3500_fKr</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:400px;width:600px;float:right;">
Description of the project</div>
<div id="map" style="height:800px;width:1000px;float:left;">
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
          var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {allOverlays: true, controls: []});
            var wms_layer_Test_5000_fKr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'Test_5000_fKr',
            'http://130.237.175.39:8080/geoserver/wms/test_test',
            {layers: 'Test_5000_fKr', transparent: "true", format: "image/png"},

            {maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(585000, 6600000, 740000, 6722500), maxResolution: 'auto', projection:"EPSG:3006", units: "m"},
            {isBaseLayer: false}, 
            {visibility: true},
            {transparent: true}
            );

      map.addLayers([wms_layer_Test_5000_fKr]);

      var scalebar = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine();
            map.addControl(scalebar);

            map.addControl(
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                    prefix: '<a target="_blank" ' +
                        'href="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3006/">' +
                        'SWEREF99 TM:&nbsp</a>',
                    separator: ' , ',
                    numDigits: 0,
                    emptyString: 'Mouse is not over map.'
                })
            );            

      var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar();
            map.addControl(panel);

      var panzoom = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar();
            map.addControl(panzoom);                                              

      var layer = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false});
            map.addControl(layer);

        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script></div>

<div id="footer" style="clear:both;text-align:left;">
Copyright © ink.su.se</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, you should probably post some code, anything you've tried really, otherwise you'll probably not get many answers, just downvotes. We love code !

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. 
In my page i have created two div elements for map object and table. i am posting those two elements of the code here. if you want to see full code you can see it in page source.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The goal of this site is to be a lasting archive of useful answers to common questions. To this end, [please put the code relevant to your question DIRECTLY into your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -- if you only provide a link to an external site, the question becomes obsolete once that site changes. (In addition, no one here can be sure your external site isn't some kind of malware host.)

Comment: I have tried to post the script here but it says too many characters it is not allowing me to submit the comment.

Comment: In that case, please make an effort to narrow down the location of the problem you're having before posting it here.

Comment: hi i have posted my script above.

Comment: More precisely i am looking for
If user press on any row it should display corresponding layer on the map. rows are basically layer list on the map with description about it.